# exp/imp commands using c# ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net, oracleclient

I have been asked to create code in c# that

1)First of all removes everything from a DB.
Right now we use SQL plus to execute the following command :

> RAMNIVAS_CC/RAMNIVAS_CC@orclwex3 set pages 0   set lines 80   spool
>   c:\delete_objects_cc   select 'drop '||object_type||'
>   '||object_name||';'   from user_objects;   spool off   start
>   c:\delete_objects_cc.lst   purge recyclebin;   set pages 100   select
>   count(*) from user_objects;

Can I execute that command using ADO.net using    command.ExecuteNonQuery(); ? count(*) is used to check if its done or now.

2) Then we store DB. I have one folder where I have kept the backup files (DMP and text).
We go to command prompt and then run the following command:

imp YOGENDRA_CA/YOGENDRA_CA@ORCLWEX3 file=CA.dmp log=CA.Log buffer=1000000 fromuser=RAMNIVAS_CA touser=YOGENDRA_CA statistics=none grants=n commit=y

Can I also Do it with the same procedure as with step 1?

3)Then restore it using command
exp YOGENDRA_CA/YOGENDRA_CA@ORCLWEX3 file=CA.dmp log=CA.log direct=y compress=y buffer=1000000 grants=n statistics=none

Comment: 1: Since a cell (the count) is returned, `ExecuteScalar()` would be the one to use (I don't know enough Oracle to answer 2/3)

Comment: @MarcGravell I want to ask if it is possible to execute the statements using ADO.NET or not.

Comment: Well, did you try it? what happened?